# Something went wrong with Google Auth only on Android

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, google-authentication

My **firebase** authentication used to work smoothly on my **IONIC** app on both iOS and Android.

Testing on Android after quite a few changes working on IOS side, I can no longer make a google login, though it still works well on iOS it gives me this on Android.

[image]

I already checked my **SHA1** and **SHA256** configuration in firebase console.
Loging in with google also works on a web browser. It only fails on Android.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in the Ionic Capacitor for android version...

Check if your SKD was automatically updated...

I don't know why it changed my SHA-1 run the command to get the SHA-1 and compare with the atual in your firebase (mine was different)

-> keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore

go inside your firebase console (console.firebase.google.com) include the new SHA-1 and download your new google-service.json, change the file in your project and try again - for me works fine

The IOS application works fine due to the firebase didnt need the sha-1, but only the package ID

***I Checked again and found that I created a new key for my project, this changed the SHA-1, so I included the SHA-1 in firebase, both for debug and release, after this, google login returned to work***

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\biel7\.android\Release.jks -alias Release
```

using the command above, returns my release SHA-1, because in my case when i tried to create the release APK the google login stopped works